# Correct usage of instance level variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an object with a few methods that access an EntityFramework entity, using it to update fields in the object before updating it ( which saves to the database)
Since multiple methods were using the EF Object, I made the entity an instance-level variable so that all could use it.

The issue is that before the Entity variable it is used it must be created. Currently this is handled fine, as there is one public method for the object which creates the entity right at the start.

Im trying to figure out if this usage of an instance level variable is correct, or if there is a better way of doing things. The issue with this current way of doing things is if the next person to work on this project makes calls to the variable before it is created.

```
public class TestClass{

private EntityObject entObject;

public void DoSomething{

  InitObject();
  DoSomethingElse();

}

 private void InitObject(){

//initialise the entity object here

}

private void DoSomethingElse(){

  //do things here, which use the entObject
  }
}
```

Comment: This is general to instance variables: these must be initialized in a constructor.

Comment: or it can be passed using Constructor injection and assigned to the instance variable

Comment: Too meta, don't understand the question. Please show me the code.

Comment: please show a simplified example that describes your problem

Answer (score 0):

The usual old-school pattern for this kind of scenario is to provide an `EnsureXXX()` method, and then call it from every location where initialization is required. For example:

```
class A
{
    private B _b;

    private void EnsureB()
    {
        if (_b == null)
        {
            _b = new B(); // or whatever;
        }
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        EnsureB();
        // Do stuff with _b
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        EnsureB();
        // Do stuff with _b
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        EnsureB();
        // Do stuff with _b
    }
}
```

A newer approach, taking advantage of the "newish" `Lazy<T>` class would look like this:

```
class A
{
    private readonly Lazy<B> _b = new Lazy<B>(() => new B());

    public void Method1()
    {
        B b = _b.Value;
        // Do stuff with b
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        B b = _b.Value;
        // Do stuff with b
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        B b = _b.Value;
        // Do stuff with b
    }
}
```

In the `Lazy<T>` version, the `Value` property winds up doing the duty of the `EnsureXXX()` method.

A middle of the road version performs the lazy initialization explicitly, but encapsulates the value in a property:

```
class A
{
    private B _b;

    private B B
    {
        get
        {
            if (_b == null)
            {
                 _b = new B();
            }

            return _b;
        }
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        // Do stuff with B
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        // Do stuff with B
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        // Do stuff with B
    }
}
```

You can even mix-and-match the `Lazy<T>` and property approaches:

```
class A
{
    private readonly Lazy<B> _b = new Lazy<B>(() => new B());

    private B B { get { return _b.Value; } }
}
```